# How can I make the text right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Who can help me to make (question_number) right in the same line with (quiz_question)?

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-1 pt-1 text-start"><b>.<?php echo $question_number; ?></b></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <?php echo remove_js(htmlspecialchars_decode($quiz_question['title'])); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an HTML and bootstrap question, not PHP. The fact that you're creating the HTML using PHP is irrelevant.

Comment: Have you actually added Bootstrap to your project? https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ If you do your content is already on the same line because of the `row` class

Comment: Do you mean to place the question_number on the right side of quiz_question?

Answer (score 0):

### Please add the "order" class using bootstrap

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-md-1 pt-1 text-start order-2"><b>.<?php echo $question_number; ?></b></div>
  <div class="col-md-9 order-1">
    <?php echo remove_js(htmlspecialchars_decode($quiz_question['title'])); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```